# Scrolling text "console like" window in wxPython?

Tags: python, text, scroll, wxpython, stdout

When you launch wxPython's wx.App(True) object, it will send stdout/stderr to a popup window.  Is there a way to tie that to a panel in my Frame object?  Please, please post code to do that!

If there is no way to do that, is there a way to create a scrolling text widget that accepts appended text from a logger that captures stdout/stderr and then sends it to that widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can quite easily duck-type an object to redirect stdout/err to as shown here http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/01/01/wxpython-redirecting-stdout-stderr/

The actual redirection is just assigning the appropriate names in `sys` to your redirect

```
sys.stdout = redirect
sys.stderr = redirect
```

Comment: Awesome!  That site has helped me before and I remember reading that very post once I saw it.  But this time it must have been when I actually needed it.  Thanks!